# How to enable iOS time-sensitive notifications switch in app settings?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios15, apple-documentation

I am working on changing the types of notifications in my app to `time-sensitive` and `active` on iOS 15+. I noticed that if I go to iPhone settings -> Notifications -> and open apps like Uber or FB Messenger I see that they have a separate flag that enables time-sensitive notifications whereas other apps do not. See attached examples of Reminders, Instagram, Facebook, and Uber.

My developer colleague and I cannot find proper documentation that explains how to enable such a setting for our users. Does it mean that any notification that we highlight in code as time-sensitive will be delivered as such by default without users' additional consent? Any advice?[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationinterruptionlevel/timesensitive and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683630 and https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc21/10091/ might help

Comment: Thanks @ShawnFrank it's not exactly what I was missing but still good general tips

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tested it on iOS15, and if you want to send time-sensitive notifications.

> 1. go to `Signing&Capabilities`, add `Time Sensitive Notifications`

[image]

> 2. Install app to your iPhone, then allow notification, you can see  `Time Sensitive Notifications` switch display in setting. And it's on by default

[image]

> 3. Send `Time Sensitive Notifications`, set  `interruptionLevel` to `timeSensitive`.

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        content.interruptionLevel = .timeSensitive
    }
```

Comment: I don't seem to have any such entry (the Time Sensitive Notification) in my signing and capabilities screen? Do I need to do something first?

Comment: @Markus The version of xcode you are using is？,I think you need to update your xcode version

Comment: It's 14.2 (14C18), but I suspect that it's because I'm not enrolled in the Developer Program.

Comment: what would be the payload of sending time senstivie notification?