# How to achieve time-sensitive flag in APNS JSON output via FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[iOS distinguishes between messages by `UNNotificationInterruptionLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification). I would like to achieve that messages sent via FCM have the `time-sensitive` `interruption-level`.

Is this equivalent to just sending messages in FCM with [high priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)? Unfortunately it's not super clear to me from looking at the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interruption level is automatically handled by system, not by FCM. That's different than the high priority.

You should be able to use it as it is by following Apple's documentation. FCM supports passing down the interruption-level in the payload.

Comment: can you please share FCM documentation on how to set  interruption-level in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by having this payload in my firebase console file:

```
var message = {
  notification: {
      title: "Notification Title",
      body: `${initiatedUsername} sent you message`,
  },
  "data": {
    "target_exec":"messaging"
   },
   "apns": {
       "payload": {
           "aps": {
               "alert": {
                 "title": "Notification Title",
                 "body": `${initiatedUsername} sent you a message`
               },
               "badge": 1,
               "sound": "default",
               "interruption-level": "time-sensitive"
           }
       }
   },
  token: fcmToken,
  };
```

You can change the token attribute to topic aswell, if you'd rather like to send a message to a topic.

Hope this might help somebody out here!

Comment: I just have enabled `Time Sensitive Notifications` in Xcode, and added `"interruption-level": "time-sensitive"` in `aps` section, and still i don't get the notification when focus is On. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: I suppose you enabled the App Configuration and Provisioning Profile on Apple Dev too?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy FCM doesn't support interruption-level. You should move to [Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=ar#node.js)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution to this problem.

An issue on GitHub confirms that it possible to handle "interruption-level": "time-sensitive" by FCM with the correct configuration.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9036

**Then:**

1. On Xcode: go to `Signing&Capabilities`, add `Time Sensitive Notifications`
2. Install app to your iPhone, then allow notification, you can see `Time Sensitive Notifications` switch display in setting. And it's on by default
3. By FCM, send `Time Sensitive Notifications`, set `interruptionLevel` to `timeSensitive`.

**An example:**

```
var message = {
  notification: {
      title: "Notification Title",
      body: `${initiatedUsername} sent you message`,
  },
  "data": {
    "target_exec":"messaging"
   },
   "apns": {
       "payload": {
           "aps": {
               "alert": {
                 "title": "Notification Title",
                 "body": `${initiatedUsername} sent you a message`
               },
               "badge": 1,
               "sound": "default",
               "interruption-level": "time-sensitive"
           }
       }
   },
  token: fcmToken,
  };
```

**References:**

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9036
- [How to enable iOS time-sensitive notifications switch in app settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111286/how-to-enable-ios-time-sensitive-notifications-switch-in-app-settings)