# How to create a critical locale notification in Swift

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I try to create a critical locale notification

Hi,

I try to create a critical locale notification like this :

[critical notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SQhc.png)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
let newNotification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        newNotification.title = "Taskko"
        newNotification.body = textNotification
        newNotification.sound = .defaultCritical
        newNotification.badge = (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "counterOfNotif")) as NSNumber
        newNotification.interruptionLevel =  .critical
```

I searched on the internet but I didn't find how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Critical notifications require a special entitlement from Apple and are used for apps such as medical alerts. My French isn’t great, but I don’t think Twitter will be sending critical notifications for live podcasts :-)

I think you are actually wanting to use a time-sensitive notification. That has an `interruptionLevel` of `.timeSensitive` and also requires an additional entitlement. However you can configure the entitlement yourself in Xcode. See [How to enable iOS time-sensitive notifications switch in app settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111286/how-to-enable-ios-time-sensitive-notifications-switch-in-app-settings)

You also won’t be able to use the `.defaultCritical` sound without the special entitlement from Apple.

If you really do want to use critical alerts you can request the entitlement here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/notifications-critical-alerts-entitlement/ (requires Apple developer login).